How to return the handshake response headers from the websocket destination route on Spring Cloud Gateway
I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway  to connect to a backend server using websockets. The route works, but the custom headers added by the destination server are not being returned to the client.
How can I return the headers to client after a successful handshake with the destination server?
Steps to simulate:

Create a Spring Cloud Gateway route on application.yaml: (code here can be found here: https://github.com/danieltnaves/gateway/tree/main)

server:
  port: 8383

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: websocket_route
          uri: ws://localhost:8080/ws
          predicates:
            - Path=/ws/**


Create a websocket server and adds a custom header: (code here can be found here: https://github.com/danieltnaves/websocket/tree/main)

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebsocketApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebsocketApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomWebSocketHandler customWebSocketHandler() {
        return new CustomWebSocketHandler();
    }
    
}

public class CustomHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
        response.getHeaders().add("X-Custom-Header", "CustomHeaderValue");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {

    }
}

public class CustomWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connection Established: " + session.getId());
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Welcome to WebSocket server!"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        // Echo the received message
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Received: " + message.getPayload()));
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connection Closed: " + session.getId());
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebsocketApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebsocketApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomWebSocketHandler customWebSocketHandler() {
        return new CustomWebSocketHandler();
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    private final CustomWebSocketHandler customWebSocketHandler;

    public WebSocketConfig(CustomWebSocketHandler customWebSocketHandler) {
        this.customWebSocketHandler = customWebSocketHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(customWebSocketHandler, "/ws")
                .addInterceptors(new CustomHandshakeInterceptor())
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}


Connect to Spring Cloud Gateway (ws://localhost:8383/ws) using Postman and see that the My-Custom-Header is missing on the response headers:


If I connect directly to the websocket server, I can see the headers:

If we try to proxy the request using Nginx for example, we will see that the headers are returned as expected as well:
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;
    upstream websocket {
        server app:8080; # Replace 'app' with your Spring Boot service name
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://spring-app:8080/ws;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}


This issue was also reported here, but no solution so far: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/2436
Thank you!
I've tried to create my own RequestUpgradeStrategy using ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy as reference, but the problem is that when we call reactorResponse.sendWebsocket from HttpServerOperations the handshake headers are returned to client and the handshake with the websocket server is executed just afterwards.
